# How did Doctor Strange repeat the scene where he made the deal with Dormammu?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

[image]

In this scene I saw that Doctor Strange was looping again and again and was repeating his dialogue again and again and Dormammu was killing him again and again.

I know that Doctor Strange had done something with time but I don't clearly understand what he did exactly.

Can anyone please explain what exactly happened in that scene?

Comment: From a previous interview I had read when the movie initially came out, the director indicated they had cut a scene where Strange says we've done this a thousand times, so I think he does remember. http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/doctor-strange-scott-derrickson/ Additionally, the last time he confronts Dormammu in the movie, he says, No, I've come to bargain, or such, changing his line. As to the idea of time on Earth being frozen, or moving forward, I remember, at this point in the movie they are in Dormammu's timeless dimension, so whatever is happening is separate from the Earth

Answer (score 36):

> *Mordo*: Temporal manipulations can create branches in time. Unstable dimensional openings. Spacious paradoxes! Time loops!!! You want to get stuck reliving the
>   same moment over, and over, forever, or never having existed at all?

> *Dormammu*: You... what is happening? 
>   *Strange*: Just as you gave Kaecilius powers from your dimension, I've brought a little power from mine. **This is time. An endless looped time.**

Before Strange confronts Dormammu, he uses the Eye of Agamotto to create an unbroken time loop. This is represented by the glowing green "bracelet" that he creates and wears. The result is Strange and Dormammu (and possibly everyone in the world) being stuck reliving the same short window of time encompassed by the time loop Strange has created.

[image: Time Loop Bracelets - functional AND stylish]

> *Strange*: Take your zealots from the Earth. End your assault on my world. Never come back. Do it, and **I'll break the loop.**

Once Dormammu has agreed to Strange's demands, he presumably uses the Eye of Agamotto's powers to break the time loop, and the bracelet is not seen again.

[image: What time bracelet? I never had a time bracelet.]

Comment: Not everyone in the world; he makes a point that everyone else will go on with their lives while they're trapped in the loop

Comment: "Yeah. But everyone on Earth will live." Not 100% the same as saying their lives will go on outside of the loop.

Comment: He probably would have got through to Dormammu much more easily if he'd started each loop with a clock radio playing "I Got You Babe".

Comment: @rickster This would have been the perfect opportunity for a rick-rolling.  "Never gonna give you up..."

Comment: Wonder if its worth mentioning that this is because the Eye is a Stone?

Comment: @rickster The traditional way is to play "what's new pussycat" for the first couple dozen loops, then switch to "It's not unusual" for one, then change back.

Comment: @Ghotir, Random832 Too subtle a [reference](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dYzVdv6V5Vs)?

Comment: @rickster Oh!  Boy, is my face red...  Indeed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the time loop existed only in Dormammu's dimension; Strange gets the idea when some other character mentions that Dormammu exists "outside of time", so Strange brought some time with him.

Answer (score 13):

Doctor Strange essentially created a "backup save" with the Eye of Agamotto (which has the time infinity stone stored inside it).  Every instance in which he died time reverted to this point, albeit Dormammu and Doctor Strange remembered the previous encounters because Dormammu "exists outside of time" and Doctor Strange wielded the eye.

This loop continued until Dormammu agreed to Strange's requests and Strange ended the loop.

Comment: Time loops man - can't trust em

Comment: An infinite time loop...not exactly a "backup save"...but yes.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was simplifying it

Comment: @TylerShads wow, you are back O.o

Comment: I've only seen the movie once, but does Strange actually remember the previous encounters? His strategy doesn't seem to rely on that, only on keeping Dormammu trapped in a time loop.

Comment: @Walt - Only saw it once as well. But probably the way to tell would be if he walks and talks *exactly* the same every time. A person who remembers would naturally try to change it up a bit.

Comment: Dormammu, at the very least, seems to remember. He asks what's going on once he realizes something is amiss.

Comment: Doramammu's threat of an eternal string of painful deaths only makes sense if Dr. Strange were to remember them.

Comment: @CortAmmon not really. He might already be aware that he will be repeating the same moment over and over again, and just deduce everything has already happened a couple of times.

Comment: @JoshPart I may be making assumptions, but I'm used to the argument that pain you don't remember can't make you suffer, but... "Then you will spend eternity dying. / Yeah. But everyone on Earth will live. / But you will suffer. / Pain is an old friend."  My interpretation is that the suffering will be from repeated deaths.

Comment: @CortAmmon The threat could also make sense if Dormammu believes Dr. Strange is uncertain about whether he will remember.

Comment: @Paulie_D a Restore Point precisely.

Comment: Doesn't Strange defend himself from whatever killed him the previous time during his first few iterations?